# Is it "Narayanaya namah" or "narayanabhyang namah"?

Tags: vishnu, mantras, narayan

I have been chanting this mantra for the past 6 months or so, no complaint, it's working well for me

> Om Shree Lakshmi Narayanaya Namah

But recently in youtube I heard another variation

> Om Lakshmi Narayanabhyang namah

I am wondering what is the correct version? or perhaps are they two different meaning?
I am not very proficient in Sanskrit, looking for some help from this community.